# Bug with logout with Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to logout with Facebook where I use login with facebook for my web application but it's not succeeding to log a user out, and when I press reload the user is logged out instead which is strange. My logout code where I try to clear the cookies is

```
class LogoutHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        current_user = main.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies,
                facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
        if current_user:
            graph = main.GraphAPI(current_user['access_token'])
            profile = graph.get_object('me')
            accessed_token = current_user['access_token']
        self.set_cookie('fbsr_' + facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, None,
                        expires=time.time() - 86400)
        self.set_cookie('fbs_' + facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, None,
                        expires=time.time() - 86400)
        self.set_cookie('fbm_' + facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, None,
                        expires=time.time() - 86400)
        self.redirect('https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://%s&access_token=%s'
                       % (self.get_host(), accessed_token))
```

Can you tell me what I should do to achieve logged out user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure modifying the facebook cookies won't help you, from their API it looks like you can just redirect them to the URL and it should resolve their cookies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how come I must reload to make sure I'm logged out?

Comment: It might simply be a browser thing, i'm not sure but i can try to look into it more and see why it would do that.